# How can I use my laptop keyboard as other laptop keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I have this small ASUS laptop from 2006 which I love its keyboard. I want to use this keyboard as my new laptop keyboard. How can I do this?

I have seen other question here [Can I use my laptop keyboard for a PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/385931/can-i-use-my-laptop-keyboard-for-a-pc), however I prefer more software solution. I do not want to disattach my ASUS keyboard completely because it is still function pretty well. Perhaps using Bluetooth connection?

Comment: What OS are they running?

Comment: Download this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One option if both computers still work, is to use a program like synergy. 
It allows you to use a keyboard and mouse from one computer to control another.

http://synergy-project.org

Comment: This software is free and better: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460

Comment: Mouse without borders only works on Windows. Synergy works on Mac and Linux and windows

Answer (score 5):

This one works on any machine with ssh X forwarding (yes, even a phone):

First, install `x2x` on the machine you want to control (the remote machine), and then on the local machine, run:

```
ssh -X remote_machine.local x2x -west -to :0.0
```

where remote_machine.local is the hostname or ip of your remote machine. this command will extend your local machine's display to the left of the screen, "attaching" the remote machine's display, so moving your cursor to the left, past the left edge of your local machine, will begin to control the cursor on the remote machine

You can use `-east`, `-north` or `-south` as well. If you want to do this from within a window, you could look into running `x2x` from an `Xnest` window.

related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/forward-mouse-and-keyboard-input-to-x-session

Answer (score 1):

You can install a VNC server on the new laptop and connect to it from your other laptop. You could still use the mouse, keyboard, and monitor of the other laptop.

Comment: The old Asus laptop is using Linux, while the newer ones is using Windows. Will it be possible? I will try.

Comment: There are VNC clients and servers for Windows and Linux. I used to use tight VNC as a client but couldn't get it working on Windows 7 (this was a long time ago) as a server so I used RealVNC as a server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [remote desktop client](http://www.rdesktop.org/) on your Linux laptop to remotely log into your new computer from your own old laptop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Input director might be want you need: http://www.inputdirector.com/

It is free and for personal non-commercial use, Windows only.